# How to add a custom parameter to a default action in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-routing

Can you please help me? I got stuck!

I implemented a single table inheritance for a model "Customer". "Person" and "Company" are "Customers". So I added two new routes to forward all requests to the `CustomersController`:

```
resources :customers                             # added by generator
resources :people,    :controller => 'customers' <== NEW
resources :companies, :controller => 'customers' <== NEW
```

What I want to do is

1. add a parameter "`type`" to the action "`new`" of resource :`customers`
2. add a default value "Person" and "Company" to the "type" parameter in both other resources (if the parameter gets inherited!?)

My goal is to be able to call

```
new_customer_path(:type => 'Person')
```

and

```
new_person_path
```

I tried the following before, but it stopped other actions (like show) from working

```
resources :people, :controller => 'customers' do
  get 'new', :on => :member, :type => 'Person'
end
```

Can anyone out there tell me about my mistake?

Comment: do you want a constraint or a mere parameter?

Comment: I think a mere parameter should do. Any suggestion for a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the parameter to the resources arguments

```
resources :people,    :controller => 'customers', :type => "Person"
resources :companies, :controller => 'customers', :type => "Company"
```

Comment: YES! That did the job! Thank you very much Mr. Wizard!

Answer (score 0):

As for new_person_path you could do:

```
map.new_person "new_person", :controller => "customers", :action => "new", :type => "person"
```

Keep in mind that having:

```
new_customer_path(:type => "person")
```

Will pass "?type=person" in the URL so your visitors will be able to change it.

Comment: He asked for rails 3.1, while your answer is related to rails 2.

Comment: Thank you anyway! How would you translate this suggestion to Rails 3.1?